# barcodescanner phonegap plugin issue

Tags: android, cordova

I'm currently trying to implement barcodescanner in my phonegap project.
But I'm completly lost because I read a lot of topics about barecodescanner and all possible solutions provided didn't work for me.

First, some tutorials and documents says that I have to use
cordova.plugin.barcodeScanner.scan (...). But for me, cordova.plugin is always undefined.

Some others says that I have to do cordova.require("cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner"); and it doesn't work, when I run my app, I get the following error : "module "cordova/plugin/BarcodeScanner" not found.

Comment: Have y ou installed the plugin? How are you building your project?

Comment: Which phonegap/cordova version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use PhoneGap Build... This is an example of implementation...

In the config.xml file add this line:

```
<!-- We'll include the Barcode plugin  -->
<gap:plugin name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" />
```

Then in the index.html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Scan() {
    cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(
      function (result) {
          window.open(result.text,'_self', 'location=no') //Opens URL in browser
          //alert("We got a barcode\n" +
          //      "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
          //      "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
          //      "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
      }, 
      function (error) {
          alert("Scanning failed: " + error);
      }
    );
}
</script>
```

To call the script with a button in the body section of page:

```
<button onclick="Scan()">Barcode</button>
```

Good luck!